# Detail formatter error: java.util.Arrays cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, arrays, string, blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I have developed a BlackBerry application where in I am reading in a `HEX String` values. The values returned are as follows:

```
String result =  response.toString();
```

where result is:
`["AC36C71DF3CB315A35BFE49A17F483B6","CF5B717ACC460E3C4545BE709E9BCB83","E1EE334738CA4FA14620639DD6750DC3","DD40E2822539C2184B652D1FC3D2B4E6","6AF4B1EAC8D8210D64A944BFD487B9F2"]`

These are passed into the following `split` method to separate the values. The method is as follows:

```
private static String[] split(String original, String separator) {
            Vector nodes = new Vector();
            int index = original.indexOf(separator);
            while (index >= 0) {
                nodes.addElement(original.substring(0, index));
                original = original.substring(index + separator.length());
                index = original.indexOf(separator);
            }
            nodes.addElement(original);
            String[] result = new String[nodes.size()];
            if (nodes.size() > 0) {
                for (int loop = 0; loop < nodes.size(); loop++) {
                    result[loop] = (String) nodes.elementAt(loop);
                    System.out.println(result[loop]);
                }
            }
            return result;
       }
```

The above array is passed is as the `String original` in the method. This part is working fine. However, when a single value is passed in as `String original`, i.e. `["6AF4B1EAC8D8210D64A944BFD487B9F2"]`, I get an error :

`Detail formatter error:java.util.Arrays cannot be resolved to a type`.

Please help !!! The values posted above are exact values as read including the parenthesis `[]` and quotations `""`

Comment: The "original" parameter to this method is a String, not a String array.  So can you clarify this statement: "The above array is passed is as the String original in the method".  Are you expecting the run time processing to convert your String array to a String?

Comment: Apologies for the incorrect information, I have edited the question, please check.

Comment: at `result[loop] = (String) nodes.elementAt(loop);`. Exception is not thrown but the value returned is null at `String[] listResult = split(result, sep);` where infact it should return a single value, i.e. when `String original = ["6AF4B1EAC8D8210D64A944BFD487B9F2"]`

Comment: Can you please update your question to confirm that your issue here is NOT the error message you have included, but the fact that the method supplied returns null rather than the single value you expect.

Comment: On which line do you get the error ?

Comment: Assuming your `separator` parameter is `","`, this code is not working as you describe.  It returns an array of 5 elements, for the full response, and an array of 1 element, for the shorter response.  The only thing that doesn't look right to me is that it includes the leading `[` with the first element, and the trailing `]` with the last one.  That can't be right.  Also, I'm not sure if it's meant to strip the quotes or not.

Answer (score 0):

The Blackberry libraries are based on [Java ME](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javame/index.html) and not [Java SE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/index.html). In Java ME some classes have been removed to reduce the runtime footprint such as the Arrays class.

Take a look at the [Blackberry JDE java.util package](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/java/util/package-frame.html), see there is no Arrays class. So in your code you cannot use methods coming from the Arrays class, you must found a workaround or implement the feature yourself.

Comment: I think the question here is either (a) why is this code using the java.util.Arrays class - I can see no reference to that class in the code, or (b) why is the result not what is expected.  I think this needs to be clarified.

Answer (score 0):

Try this split method -

```
 public static String[] split(String strString, String strDelimiter) {
    String[] strArray;
    int iOccurrences = 0;
    int iIndexOfInnerString = 0;
    int iIndexOfDelimiter = 0;
    int iCounter = 0;

    //Check for null input strings.
    if (strString == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input string cannot be null.");
    }
    //Check for null or empty delimiter strings.
    if (strDelimiter.length() <= 0 || strDelimiter == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Delimeter cannot be null or empty.");
    }
    if (strString.startsWith(strDelimiter)) {
        strString = strString.substring(strDelimiter.length());
    }
    if (!strString.endsWith(strDelimiter)) {
        strString += strDelimiter;
    }
    while((iIndexOfDelimiter = strString.indexOf(strDelimiter,
           iIndexOfInnerString)) != -1) {
        iOccurrences += 1;
        iIndexOfInnerString = iIndexOfDelimiter +
            strDelimiter.length();
    }

    strArray = new String[iOccurrences];
    iIndexOfInnerString = 0;
    iIndexOfDelimiter = 0;
    while((iIndexOfDelimiter = strString.indexOf(strDelimiter,
           iIndexOfInnerString)) != -1) {

        strArray[iCounter] = strString.substring(iIndexOfInnerString,iIndexOfDelimiter);
        iIndexOfInnerString = iIndexOfDelimiter +
        strDelimiter.length();
        iCounter += 1;
    }

    return strArray;
}
```

Comment: It's fine to paste in the full code, but you should include a link to indicate that this code came [from this page](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/String-Manipulation-split-replace-replaceAll/ta-p/620038).  Also, viewers should look at Eugen's comments at the bottom of the page ... apparently, nobody tested this code before posting it :(

Comment: @Nate i pasted this code from my project. I don't know from where i got this code. I tested this code and its working fine for me.

Comment: Basically, Eugen's comment was about error handling.  Notice what happens if `strDelimiter` is null.  If the parameters passed in are good, it'll probably work fine.  However, he also mentioned that it's not terribly efficient.  However, the method Sarah posted to split strings also works.  So, she's having some other problem.

Comment: The String value returned from the database is in the format ["abc"]. This is the exact value. When this one value is passed to the split method, the array returned contains the value ["abc"] including the quotation and brackets. This seems to be causing the error message `Detail formatter error: java.util.Arrays cannot be resolved to a type`. With more than one vale returned from the database, I am able to chop off the brackets and quotation and thus that works. Please help here.

Comment: i think, the response is in json array format. you directly converting the json array into string.